# is there a in built feature in firebase to compose forms to make entries to the database

Tags: forms, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database where I am storing records. Is there anything already existing features in firebase by which I can use/compose a form to make entries to the database?

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase console has a panel where you can see and manipulate the data in your Firebase Database. But beyond that, there is no functionality in the SDKs to help you build edit forms.